# Google Recaptcha v2 Accessibility: NVDA Screen Reader audio collides/overlaps with Audio Challenge Playback after clicking on Play button

Tags: recaptcha, nvda

We have noticed with NVDA screen reader in Chrome (maybe same in other browsers) that after clicking on Play button, the control/focus is automatically sent to input field which has a label "Enter numbers you hear". It is difficult to hear the first number being said in the audio.

Can the audio playback be delayed for 1 or 2 seconds after clicking on PLAY button to avoid this overlapping issue? or else can the control stay on PLAY button instead of automatically going to audio response input text field?

Any suggestions please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Work Around Found:

Press R to replay the audio message as mentioned in the help text :) All 5 numbers in the audio can be heard clearly without any overlap with NVDA instructions (it just says R quickly and the audio numbers follow).

I can now say that Recaptcha v2 is awesomely accessible. Great work !!!